# How to run the code and write the file in the hidden folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I have a code to zip all folders it still works normally outside but when the path

```
'C:\Users\Dr Corn\AppData\Local\Temp'
```

It does not work again
Here is my code:

```
from posixpath import dirort
import zipfile
import os

path = r'C:\Users\Dr Corn\AppData\Local\Temp'

folders = os.listdir(path)

for folder in folders:
     if os.path.isdir(folder):
         print(folder)
         with zipfile.zipfile(folder + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.zip_deflated) as newzip:
             for dirpath, dires, files in os.walk(folder):
                 for files in files:
                     newzip.write(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
```

We look forward to your help, thank you for reading

Comment: Python is case sensitive.

Comment: It's hard to look at code that looks like this, learn a bit about the [pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) standard.

Answer (score 0):

The code shared in question has lot of case related issues as noted by @AvleMonke.

If attempt in code is to create a zip file for each directory in the path given then following is the modified version of code in question that works.

```py
from posixpath import *
import zipfile
import os

path = r'C:\Test\Dr Corn\App Data\Local\Temp'

folders = os.listdir (path)

for folder in folders:
    
    folder_full_path = path+'\\'+folder
    if os.path.isdir (folder_full_path):
        
        with zipfile.ZipFile (folder_full_path + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as newzip:
            for dirpath, dires, files in os.walk (folder_full_path):
                for files in files:
                    newzip.write (os.path.join (dirpath, files))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, let me ask another question if I want that zip file to be saved in another path, how to do it?

Comment: dirpath in newzip.write (os.path.join (dirpath, files)) dictates where you need to place zip files. Change it as needed.